# Собщите, когда был последний перерасчет ЖКХ(,) и получили ли Вы квитанцию

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, придаточное-предложение

> Сообщите, был ли последний перерасчет ЖКХ(,) и получили ли Вы квитанцию.

Нужна ли здесь запятая — и почему?!

А в таком варианте?

> Сообщите, когда был последний перерасчет ЖКХ(,) и получили ли Вы квитанцию.

Comment: Вопрос был некорректно сформулирован, тем не менее в комментариях получен исчерпывающий ответ. Дальнейшее обсуждение вопроса в таком виде бессмысленно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже на **письменный запрос**:

**Сообщите, когда был последний перерасчет ЖКХ и получили ли Вы квитанцию.**

Однородные изъяснительные придаточные. "Сильно выраженной" вопросительной интонации нет, поэтому в конце предложения ставим точку. Но постановка вопросительного знака тоже не исключается.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

Другая коммуникативная ситуация  (без однородных придаточных) вроде бы не просматривается.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Я не вижу разницы между этими вариантами, в обоих случаях это однородные изъяснительные придаточные (косвенные вопросы).

Comment: Jasmin, ну что Вы, в самом деле?! Вы, похоже, вообще вопроса не поняли совершенно. Вопросительный знак там не относится к тексту "запроса", как вы это назвали. Это я задаю вопрос Вам. Там же даже кавычки были вполне корректно поставленные. А вопрс был о запятой. Я отредактировал на всяк случай, теперь понятнее?

Comment: Я на всякий случай ответила про вопросительный знак, не могу понять, чем отличаются варианты. Три раза перечитала, может быть, у меня что-то с компьютером.

Comment: Они отличаются словом "когда", которое в данном случае похоже на подчинительный союз, а это меняет грамматику фразы.  Не уверен, что это изменение существенно для пунктуации, но суть-то моего  вопроса была именно в том, как тут обосновать запятую (или отсутствие её) через правила, относящиеся к БСП/ССП/СПП. А вот как применить правило об общем члене в соподчиненных предложениях к БСС или хотя бы к ССП, я не очень понимаю.

Comment: Это СПП с однородными изъяснительными придаточными, союзное слово КОГДА и частица ЛИ в роли союза. Хотя придаточные имеют разную структуру, они оба передают информацию, которую запрашивают, и относятся к одному опорному слову, поэтому они однородны.

Comment: А.... Я понял. Моя вина. Я действительно по склерозу два раза написал одно и тоже. Имелось в виду, что один вариант без "когда". То есть ві полагаете, что "ли" здесь союзное слово? єто меняет дело, конечно, но что-то сомнительно... Ладно, спасибо, я подумаю, можно ли предложение и без "ли" написать.

Comment: Да, хорошо, что всё прояснилось. Но вот интересно, о каких вариантах говорил в ответе  Alex_ander?

Comment: Похоже, он меня изначально понял лучше. Вопреки всем моим усилиям. И я его тоже понял. Речь как раз о тех вариантах, о которых я хотел спросить. Другое дело, что я не совсем согласен с самим ответом... Но обсуждать уже глупо, поскольку вопрос уже совсем "не от того ответа".

Answer (score 1):

В первом варианте запятая не нужна из-за наличия обобщающего "сообщите".
В варианте с вопросительным знаком нужны средства для превращения второй части в вопросительное предложение, отделённое по смыслу от "сообщите" (иначе оно будет этому противоречить из-за своего обобщающего действия: нельзя обобщить вопрос с повествованием). Для этого можно поставить точку с запятой (если не точку, заканчивающую первое предложение), а союз "и" при этом придётся убрать.

Comment: Вы очень много рассуждений привели, но, боюсь, не вникли в проблему. *В первом варианте запятая не нужна из-за наличия обобщающего "сообщите".* - вы как, простите, трактуете грамматику предложения? Если это СПП, то где подчинительный союз?!  А если ССП (тем более - БСП), то какое у ним отношение имеет правило об общем члене?!